# Crystal Reports - Suppress formula repeated

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, basic

I have a Crystal Reports report, It contains 3 sub reports in 3 different details sections. (details a, details b, details c)

If I set suppress formula that use data from DB to the details section b and c

```
ISNULL({Table.Field})
```

When I generate a report the whole details section (a,b and c) is repeated multiple times and data duplicated from a 3-93 pages report.

My data is structured ads follow:

```
DataSource: ReportDS
Table: Client (Showed in details a)
 -Name
 -Surname
 -...
Table: Order (Showed in details b repeated for any order in datasource)
 -Date
 -Total
 -...
Table: Product (Showed in details c repeated for any product in datasource)
 -Name
 -Price
```

Section b suppress formula:

```
IF ISNULL({Order.Total}) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
```

Section c suppress formula:

```
IF ISNULL({Product.Name}) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
```

Comment: where did you write the supress formula?

Comment: Right click on the details section b -> section expret -> suppress flag -> formula 
AND
Right click on the details section c -> section expret -> suppress flag -> formula

Comment: are there 3 datasources or single datasource?

Comment: Single datasource

Comment: if its a single source then edit the question on what data you are showing in each of the detail sections and what is the condition you are using in supress on detail section b and c

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: So what is your supress condition in this scenario?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it again

Comment: Looking at your report structure, if you are trying to make some relation between 3 sub reports then suggested approach is to link all 3 tables and then instead of sub report, develop in single report, if you see 3 sub reports differently means those are mutually not related then your report is behaving correctly, Also if you are really worried then one suggestion is to place the sub reports on report header instead of details

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you tried adding the suppress command to the Format Subreport itself? Use its Format section.
2. If that does not work, bring the suppress command into the subreport and suppress all its sections.

Comment: 1) I've tried but the problem persist
2) The problem is that I read data from an XML and if the XML doesn't contains the information about that section crystal reports throw an exception

Comment: CR throws the exception because a missing column of data from the XML is causing the datasource for your report to have a different schema than the report expects.  To correct this you need to modify the way your datasource is created to ensure all of the columns are always present.  You should be able to do this in your C# code.  If you update this question with the code you are using to construct your datasource myself of one or the others here could help with that.  A new question may even be appropriate.